# Loading multiple text files from a single directory in matlab

Tags: matlab, batch-processing

First time here so please be gentle

So the basic idea is i have folders with just txt files that has about 20000 points each. I only want specific intervals from each of them.

I have a made a single file with the ranges for that looks like this
                                                                                             .        `2715 2955
 1132 1372`

each row representing the range i want in one file

I want to batch load all the files and export the just the ranges of each. Ive lost too much sleep over this please help

```
    dirName = '*';              %# folder path
 files = dir( fullfile(dirName,'*.txt') );   %# list all *.xyz files
  files = {files.name}' ;                     %'# file names
 data = cell(numel(files),1)  ;              %# store file contents
 for u=1:numel(files)
   A=files{u}  ;   %# full path to file
 files{u};

   STR1 = A

  B=load(STR1);
  end
```

This is all i have come up with in 2 days. im new to matlab
Thanks

Comment: Please describe what's wrong with your code. What is `dirName = '*'; ` supposed to do?

Comment: so thats where i load the directory i have all the separate text files. it would look something like C:\Users\work. edit sorry where i set path

Comment: the problem is its not loading all the files. I think if i managed to get the files in the i can use `newfilename[range(1,1):range(2,1)]` then export that

Answer (score 0):

A very good help is the matlab help of fscanf, http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/fscanf.html. Also, in your load you don't have the path. Replace the last two lines in your for loop with:

```
STR1 = [dirName A]
fileID = fopen(STR1,'r');
formatSpec = '%f';
B = fscanf(fileID,formatSpec)
```

Or try:

```
delim = ' '; 
nrhdr = 0; 
STR1 = [dirName A]
A = importdata(STR1, delim, nrhdr);
```

A.data will be your data, I'm assuming no header lines.